Нужно ли тире перед «(то) что надо»?
Концерт (—) что надо.
Обязательно ли тире?
Концерт (—) то(,) что надо. А здесь? Запятая нужна или это какое-то цельное по смыслу выражение?

О контекста зависит.

Концерт что нАдо, давно таких не было.
Хороший концерт! — Да, концерт что нАдо!
Хороший концерт! — Согласен. КонцЕрт — что нАдо!  Пауза,  два ударения.

Масса впечатлений! КонцЕрт — то  что нАдо!


То что надо — неразложимое сочетание в значении высокой оценки.
 № 257690
здравствуйте. нужна ли запятая перед "что" : Я рассмотрел 
 ваше предложение — то что надо. какими членами предложения 
 здесь являются "то" и "что"?
 ОТВЕТ
 Запятая не нужна. В значении 'хороший, годный' слова то что 
 надо выступают в роли неразложимого по смыслу сочетания и 
 не разделяются запятыми...

